# Elasticsearch aggregation with hyphenated values splitting into separate values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to retrieve an aggregation of tags (with counts) from Elasticsearch, but where I have hyphenated tags, they're getting split returned as separate tags.

E.g.

```
{
    "tags": ['foo', 'foo-bar', 'cheese']
}
```

I get back (abridged):

```
{
  'foo': 8,
  'bar': 3,
  'cheese' : 2
}
```

When I'm expecting to get:

```
{
  'foo': 5,
  'foo-bar': 3,
  'cheese' : 2
}
```

My mapping is:

```
{
    "asset" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string"},
            "path" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "url": {"type" : "string"},
            "tags" : {"type" : "string", "index_name" : "tag"},
            "created": {"type" : "date"},
            "updated": {"type" : "date"},
            "usages": {"type" : "string", "index_name" : "usage"},
            "meta": {"type": "object"}
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need an analyzer for `tags` that shouldn't split on "-". What are operations need to happen for `tags` (lowercase, trim etc)?

Comment: I need to be able to return documents by single, or multiple tags. So where tag = "foo", or where tag = "foo" AND tag = "cheese". Which works currently, its just the analyser then in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another analyzer, not the standard one which will split the words when certain characters are encountered:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword_lowercase": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "trim"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "asset" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string"},
            "path" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
            "url": {"type" : "string"},
            "tags" : {"type" : "string", "index_name" : "tag", "analyzer":"my_keyword_lowercase"},
            "created": {"type" : "date"},
            "updated": {"type" : "date"},
            "usages": {"type" : "string", "index_name" : "usage"},
            "meta": {"type": "object"}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've managed to get it working just by specifying the built-in "whitespace" analyser, but thanks for the example of adding a custom one!

Comment: Can I apply this to a `_search` query after the fact (the index is already created and can't modify the mapping)? My `aggs` query returns the values split on the dash "-" character

Comment: In Elasticsearch there is an index time analyzer (which cannot be changed after the documents have already been indexed) and a search time analyzer (which will not change what is already indexed but will change the _searched elements_. Answering your question is impossible without more details (the mapping, the query you are trying out, some sample documents, and what exactly doesn't work as expected). I would suggest creating a new post.